# How this function works with array without a loop?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Here is my sample function.

```js
    let array = ["x", "y", "z", 4, 5];
    
    function print(arr, pos, len) {
      if (pos < len) {
        console.log(arr[pos]);
        print(arr, pos + 1, len);
      }
      return;
    }
    print(array, 0, array.length);
```

The array prints each one by one. But how this is happening without a loop? any one clarify to understand the function process here?

Comment: Look up recursion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: Notice that when `print` is called, if there are still letters remaining, it calls `print` again.

Comment: Just swap `console.log(arr[pos]);
        print(arr, pos + 1, len);` and it will print array in reverse order. Its recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is this happening without a loop?

It is using *[recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))*, this means the function itself is called from within the function. Using a loop is not the only way to iterate over a collection.

If you look at your code the `print` function is called once outside your function, but also inside the `print` function itself. So when we first run your function with the array `[1, 2, 3]` we run the function with the following arguments:

```
print([1, 2, 3], 0, 3)
```

Then when we enter the function, we look at the `if` statement and see that `pos` (0) is in fact less than `len` (3). So, we then go ahead and `console.log(arr[0])` which will print the first item in your array.

We then proceed to the next line, and call `print` again, but this time from within the function. We now call it with the following arguments:

```
print([1, 2, 3], 1, 3)
```

This, again, will go through and look at the `if` statement, see that it is true, and run `console.log(arr[1])`. Once again, we will call `print` with the following arguments:

```
print([1, 2, 3], 2, 3)
```

This will then `console.log(arr[2])` (the last item in the array) and again call `print` with the following arguments:

```
print([1, 2, 3], 3, 3)
```

however, this time, our `if` statement is not met / not true, as `pos` (3) is not less than `len` (3). In other words, our *base case* (the condition to stop the recursion) is met. So, what we do instead of printing is `return`.

Doing a `return` will take us back to where we last called our `print` statement, this means we will go back to inside the `if` statement from our previous call to `print` and then `return` again once the `if` statement is complete. This unravelling process continues until we `return` to our original call of `print` (outside the `print` function declaration). Our program then terminates after this as there is no more code to run.

Answer (score 1):

> The process in which a **function calls itself** directly or indirectly is
>   called recursion and the corresponding function is called as recursive
>   function

In your scenario this means that `print` is called multiple times from inside its function body to print the array contents.

```
let array = ["x", "y", "z", 4, 5];

function print(arr, pos, len) { // <-- notice current position is passed as parameter
  if (pos < len) {              // <-- keep doing it until end of the array
    console.log(arr[pos]);      // <-- prints to the console the value at current position
    print(arr, pos + 1, len);   // <-- print function is called again with dif. pos!
  }
  return;
}
print(array, 0, array.length);  // <-- call the print function with 0 and 5 as parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a recursive function:

Read blog it is to simple and very effective: [click Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/)